# Partition a dataset by multiple conditions TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rank

I got an interesting requirement to partition a dataset using different conditions.

Say, it is not simple `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` I have to say at first place.

Is it a ranking? Yeah little bit closer, but the challenge here is to write a single query for that.

Well I'm still wondering and looking for a straight forward option. Let me introduce a problem.

```
Name ----- Age ----- MarksForMaths ---- AvgByTotal
```

Above is a simple sample schema where it can be a marks taken by few students for maths and all average marks.

I need to filter out this set based on following criterias.

1. people who got  *75 > Mathsmarks > 50*  should be on top
2. people who got  *Mathsmarks > 90* should be a next set
3. people who *average > 65* should take place thereafter
4. Older people *Age > 55* should be a last set

Yeah obviously rank and filter is an option but can we do it in a optimized query?

Tip - what I did basically is create a additional column name `RANK` and update the column with a index based on conditions.

Then it's just a matter or filter the data order by `RANK`. Piece of cake !

But the question here is , can we go for one shot query? Appreciate tips.

Thanks

Comment: where does your data come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the below query fits with your requirement :

```
DECLARE @BaseTable TABLE (Name VARCHAR(50), Age INT, MarksForMaths INT, AvgByTotal INT)

INSERT INTO @BaseTable (Name, Age, MarksForMaths, AvgByTotal)
SELECT 'A', 1, 65, 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, 5, 75 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 1, 95, 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 65, 65, 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 65, 5, 12

SELECT tmp.Name, tmp.TmpRank
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Name,
        CASE 
             WHEN (MarksForMaths > 50 AND MarksForMaths < 75) THEN 1
             WHEN (MarksForMaths > 90) THEN 2
             WHEN (AvgByTotal > 65) THEN 3
             WHEN (Age > 55) THEN 4
             ELSE 5 
       END AS TmpRank
    FROM @BaseTable
)   tmp
ORDER BY tmp.TmpRank
```